# global array won't read in to console window c#

Tags: c#, arrays, global

Schedule.cs

```
public static class SchArray
{

    public static string[] clientName = new string[20];
    public static DateTime[] startDate = new DateTime[20];
    public static DateTime[] endDate = new DateTime[20];
    public static string[] allocatedDriver = new string[20];
    public static string[] depot = new string[20];
    public static int count = 3;
}

public void schedule()
{

    SchArray.clientName[0] = "eric cartman";
    SchArray.clientName[1] = "peter griffin";
    SchArray.clientName[2] = "homer simpson";
    SchArray.startDate[0] = Convert.ToDateTime("2016,3,2");
    SchArray.startDate[1] = Convert.ToDateTime("2016,3,4");
    SchArray.startDate[2] = Convert.ToDateTime("2016,3,5");
    SchArray.endDate[0] = Convert.ToDateTime("2016,3,3");
    SchArray.endDate[1] = Convert.ToDateTime("2016,3,5");
    SchArray.endDate[2] = Convert.ToDateTime("2016,3,6");
    SchArray.allocatedDriver[0] = "owen";
    SchArray.allocatedDriver[1] = "daniel";
    SchArray.allocatedDriver[2] = "owen";
    SchArray.depot[0] = "depot1";
    SchArray.depot[1] = "depot2";
    SchArray.depot[2] = "depot3";
}
```

Work_Schedule.cs

```
public void schedule()
{

    Console.Clear();
    Console.WriteLine(" Create Work Schedule ");

    Console.WriteLine(Schedule.SchArray.clientName[0]);
    Console.ReadKey();
}

Console.WriteLine(Schedule.SchArray.clientName[0]);
```

^^^^^ this line should display the name the eric cartman, i've debugged it and it says there are no objects in the array, they're are all null.

Comment: Why not an array of a class with clientName/startDate/endDate etc properties

Comment: 1. Use OO! 2. Did you call `Schedule.schedule()` ?

Comment: You're not showing the relevant code.  Where do you call `schedule()`?

Comment: thanks, I clearly forgot to call schedule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an object of `Schedule` since the array elements ware initialized inside the constructor:

```
   Schedule scheduleObject = new Schedule();
   Console.WriteLine(SchArray.clientName[0]);
```

For this particular scenario, i would like to suggest a different approach of creating a static list/array of objects. Let me modify the class as like the following:

```
public class SchArray
    {
        public string clientName;
        public DateTime startDate;
        public DateTime endDate;
        public string allocatedDriver;
        public string depot;
        public int count = 3;
    }
```

And i have a `List<SchArray>` defined as static;

```
public static List<SchArray> StaticSchArray = new List<SchArray>();
```

Then i can populate the list as like the following:

```
 StaticSchArray.Add(new SchArray() {clientName="eric cartman",
                               startDate=Convert.ToDateTime("2016,3,2"),
                               endDate= Convert.ToDateTime("2016,3,2"),
                               depot="depot1",allocatedDriver ="owen" });
```

Similarly other elements can also be added to the array. this will be a better option for this scenario.